# how to find if specific value exists in a key, and then extract that array in new array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [CODE] => OK
        [company_id] => 170647449000
        [taxnumber] => 944703420
        [name] => SOME NAME
        [title] => S.A

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [CODE] => OK
        [company_id] => 17063649000
        [taxnumber] => 999033420
        [name] => SOME OTHER NAME
        [title] => ANOTHER DIFFERENT TITLE
    )
)
```

If the array contain the company_id with the value 17063649000 I need to extract that array (1) in an new array, so I can manipulate it further.

I make numerous code snippets but I am not even close to the solution. I still can not figure out how can I find if the $value (17063649000) exists in the array....not to mention how to extract that specific array (1) from the existing array....
My latest attempt was to modify this and to make it to work, but I am still not managing to make it:

```
function myfunction($agents, $field, $value)
{
   foreach($agents as $key => $agent)
   {
     if ( $agent[$field] === $value )
        return $key;
  }
 return false;
}
```

I always get false, even I am sending the value that exists.

Comment: you are lazy, post your code first, we won't do it for you

Comment: question has been updated as requested.

Comment: @user2417624 please show me how you use this function.

Comment: my bad, I had 2 same company id's with copy-paste mistake. I have corrected that now. I apologize if I confuse any of you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `return $key` with `return $agent` and operator `===` with `==`.
`===` checks type too, it could be reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I will be able to accept your answer in 3 min.

Answer (score 0):

if your array is $companies then

```
function getCompany($search_id, $companies) {
    foreach($company in $companies) {
        if ($companies['company_id'] == $search_id) {
            return $company;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$companies = [...];
$search = 17063649000;
if ($company = getCompany($search, $companies) ) {
    // do something with $company
} else {
    // not found
}
```